# How to bring below column's value(factor) to other new column in R

Tags: r

I want to bring the same value from other column(factor) to a new column (in factor, I guess).

I get this error.

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, e, value = structure(10L, .Label = c("RSE7056",  ... :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I've tried the below code

```
  for (e in 1:(a-1)) {
    if (data7$Freq[e]>1 && data7$RSE_ID[e] == data7$BEFORE_RSE_ID[e+1] && data7$NOW_COLCT_YMDHMS2[e] == data7$BEFORE_COLCT_YMDHMS2[e+1])  {
      data7$AFTER_RSE_ID[e] <- as.factor(data7$RSE_ID[e-1])
      data7$AFTER_time[e] <- 1
    }    
  }
```

I expect `data7$AFTER_RSE_ID[e]` be the same `RSE~` as `data7$RSE_ID[e-1]`
but it turns into three digit numbers.

The characters are as follows.

```
$ BEFORE_RSE_ID       : Factor w/ 404 levels "RSE1501","RSE1502",..: 309 160 160 159 166 188 169 183 188 169 ...
$ RSE_ID              : Factor w/ 26 levels "RSE7056","RSE7058",..: 7 10 10 7 26 8 13 12 17 14 ...
 $ AFTER_RSE_ID        : Factor w/ 26 levels "158","160","161",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
result from the code I made
```

[THE code I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UL0r.png)

[the whole result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4yi1.png)

[THE result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPX97.png)

[THE result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ogz.png)

Comment: You could convert the `factor` to character first to change the error

Comment: If you could show a small reproducible example with expected output, it would be easier to help.  Also, instead of `for` loop, this could be done more efficiently

Comment: I've add 4 pictures for easy understanding

Comment: I can't test with an image.  Please use `dput` to show the example.  Based on your code, I added a soluiton, not tested though

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the type of the column which is `factor` and when add some new values to that column, the `levels` should be preassigned or use a new `factor` column or easier would be to convert to `character` with `as.character`.  Also, instead of the `for` loop, value comparisons with the next element can be done with `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
data7 %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% # change factor columns to character
    mutate(ind =Freq > 1 & 
               (RSE_ID == lead(BEFORE_RSE_ID,default = first(BEFORE_RSE_ID))) &
  (NOW_COLCT_YMDHMS2 == lead(BEFORE_COLCT_YMDHMS2, 
                     default = first(BEFORE_COLCT_YMDHMS2))),
       AFTER_RSE_ID = case_when(ind~ lag(RSE_ID), TRUE ~ RSE_ID),
      AFTER_time = as.integer(ind))
```

Comment: sorry for my short english. I will review it later. I've fixed it though